# Is there any way to know the number of variadic function arguments specific to Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variadic-functions

First, [there's no portable way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2598140/57428) to compute the length of `va_list`. Perhaps there's a way to do this in debug (not optimized) configuration of Visual C++?

Specifically I have a variadic function:

```
void MyVariadic( const char* format, ... )
{
}
```

(and I cannot change the signature) and I want to detect cases where `format` contains percentage characters and the arguments list is empty (which likely means that someone passed a whatever string directly in place of `format` instead of using `%s`) and once I detect such cases I can `assert()` or something.

Is there a way to do this in debug non-optimized build in Visual C++?

Comment: Can you _add_ another signature? `void MyVariadic(const char* plain)` is a better match when only one string is provided.

Comment: @MSalters: Perhaps that would do, but will overload resolution properly handle this? I'd also want to forward the call to the variadic version - is that possible?

Comment: Yes, overload resolution will prefer a non-vararg function over a vararg function. That makes forwarding a bit tricky, but here you can forward to `MyVariadic("%s", plain)` and ignore that trickery.

Comment: @MSalters: I think that's just great, especially this way to make the forwarding. Could you please add this as an answer?

Comment: In C++11, You may use `template <typename ... Args> void MyVariadic(const char* format, Args&&...args)`

Answer (score 4):

Since you are okay with Visual C++-specific solutions and if your goal is to help detect mismatched printf-style format strings, consider using [SAL Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx). A build that you run with code analysis turned on will report errors if the format string and the arguments don't match up.

The annotation you want is `_Printf_format_string_`. Take a look at how `printf` is annotated in `stdio.h` for inspiration.

Consider the following code:

```
int i = 12;
printf("%d %s", i);
```

Visual C++ 2013 run with code analysis reports for me

> C6063 Missing string argument to 'printf' that corresponds to specifier '2'.

Comment: Well, this won't really work in my case - I want to detect strings that are not yet known in compile time. Such as someone writes `MyVariadic(someStringVariable)` and `someStringVariable` is set to a string with percentage signs during runtime.

Answer (score 2):

(From comments)

The problem is basically in calls like `MyVariadic(str)` where `str` is a `const char[]` known only at runtime. We can't change the signature of `void MyVariadic(const char*, ...)` but we can add an overload. `void MyVariadic(const char*)` is a better match.

From `void MyVariadic(const char* str)` it's hard to forward to `void MyVariadic(const char*, ...)`. The generic solution is to cast `&MyVariadic` to `void (*p)(const char*, ...)` but in this particular case `const char*` is a printf-like format. That means we can forward to `MyVariadic("%s", str)`.

Comment: I actually tried this with VC++ and gcc (on ideone.com) and both think the call is ambiguous.

Comment: You're not calling the function from inside `main()`. Add this: `MyVariadic("s");` into `main()` and it no longer compiles.

Comment: @sharptooth: Oops, you're right. I'm clearly overlooking something because I was quite certain that unused varargs decreased overload viability.

Comment: @sharptooth: [Fixed](http://ideone.com/NOsfjK) at the price of a dummy template argument. Signature is technically untouched.

Comment: It's not necessary to put the dummy argument onto the variadic function - it can be just as well put onto the newly introduced non-variadic function. This solves the problem - the original function is untouched and there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use variadic macro (with hardcoded limit):

```
#define COUNT_N(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, N, ...)    N
#define COUNT(...)   COUNT_N(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
// Warning: COUNT() return 1 (as COUNT(A)) :-/
#define ARG1(S, ...) S
```

And then do something like:

```
#define MyVariadic_And_Check(...) do { \
    Check(ARG1(__VA_ARGS__), COUNT(__VA_ARGS__) - 1); \
    MyVariadic(__VA_ARGS__); } while(false)
```

With `Check(const char* format, int count)` a function to check parameter count.
Note: Since MyVariadic has at least `const char* format`, `COUNT` will give correct answer.

In C++11, you may use something like:

```
template <typename ... Args>
void MyVariadic_And_Check(const char* format, Args&&...args);
```

to verify both count and type.