# How do I return the number of arguments of a function?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, variadic-templates

For example if I have

```
int MyFunction(int,...);//no. of parameters is unknown
```

And in main()

```
MyFunction(1,2,3,4);
```

The returned value should be 4.I've tried stdarg.h but to use that you have to know the number of parameters, so it doesn't hold up for me.Thanks!

Comment: First solution that comes in mind would be creating a va_list https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic and applying one of the answers provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598132/length-of-va-list-when-using-variable-list-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just return the number of arguments in a parameter pack.

```
template<typename ...Args>
unsigned MyFunction(Args... args) {
    return sizeof...(args);
}

int main() {
    return MyFunction(1,2,3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may learn and use `variadic template`s, as follows

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Types>
size_t func(Types ... args){

    return sizeof...(args);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func(1, 2, 3, 4);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if the `Args` is lowercase like `args` since it is a variable and not type.