# Check if there are variadic arguments in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have the following log function

```
void log_error(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code) {
    printf("%s:%d:%s\n", file_name, line_num, get_err_str(err_code));
}
```

I want to change this to have the option to pass a custom format string and args for additional information something like

```
void log_error(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code, ...) {
    va_list ptr;
    char * fmt;
    printf("%s:%d:%s", file_name, line_num, get_err_str(err_code));

    va_start(ptr, err_code);
    fmt = va_arg(ptr, char *);

    vprintf(fmt, ptr);
    printf("\n");
}
```

but I don't want to enforce passing this extra info, so I might not get `fmt` and the required extra arguments which might cause the code to fail, is there a way to check if there are variadic args before trying to access them? Or the only option for my use case is defining 2 different function, like so

```
void log_error(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code) {
    printf("%s:%d:%s\n", file_name, line_num, get_err_str(err_code));
}

void log_error(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code, const char * fmt, ...) {
   va_list ptr;
    printf("%s:%d:%s", file_name, line_num, get_err_str(err_code));

    va_start(ptr, err_code);
    vprintf(fmt, ptr);
    printf("\n");
    va_end(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Isn't `log_error` wrapped in a macro?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598132/length-of-va-list-when-using-variable-list-arguments

Answer (score 2):

You can't check for variadic arguments in functions without at least one non-variadic argument that tells you what is going on, but you CAN use a variadic macro that expands to the "right" variadic function call.  Since you are probably already using a macro to supply `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, you can probably do something like:

```
// this is the function that will be called by the macro
void log_error_func(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code, const char *fmt, ...);

// this is the macro that will be used to log
#define log_error(CODE, ...) log_error_func(__FILE__, __LINE__, CODE, "" __VA_ARGS__)
```

Now you can use things like

```
log_error(42, "this error has args: %d, %d, %d", 1, 2, 3);
```

as well as

```
log_error(5);   /* no args here */
```

and they'll work as one would expect.  The use of `""` in a macro like this requires that the format arg (if present) be string literal, so the empty string will be properly prepended.

Comment: Suggest `__LINE__, CODE, ""` --> `__LINE__, (CODE), ""` for the usual macro reasons.

Comment: `"" __VA_ARGS__` --> nice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: this one case where it can't possibly make a difference -- comma is lower precedence than anything else, AND `CODE` cannot possibly contain a comma-op (unless already parenthesized).  While it is safe to add parens, of course, it smacks of cargo-cult programming.

Comment: But the planes always arrived when I used `()`! - (yes, apparently the `()` are not needed.) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't have any way of knowing whether or not a format string has been passed.  So the best thing to do is to make it an explicit parameter.

```
void log_error(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code, char * fmt, ...) {
    va_list ptr;
    printf("%s:%d:%s", file_name, line_num, get_err_str(err_code));

    va_start(ptr, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, ptr);
    va_end(ptr);
    printf("\n");
}
```

For a function like this, I would expect that a message string would have to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to check if there are variadic args before trying to access them?

No.

> the only option for my use case is defining 2 different function, like so

Generally, yes, or similar.

You can make `log_error` a macro, and overload the macro on the number of arguments. 3 arguments would go to the first version, more would go to the variadic one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single funtion, you MUST have a `fmt` parameter, but you can pass an empty string (`""`) as that argument when it's not needed. Or you can modify your code to check if `fmt` is `NULL`, if that looks neater to you:

```
void log_error(char *file_name, int line_num, int err_code, char *fmt, ...) {
    printf("%s:%d:%s", file_name, line_num, get_err_str(err_code));
    if (fmt != NULL) {
        va_list ptr;
        va_start(ptr, fmt);
        vprintf(fmt, ptr);
        va_end(ptr);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to check if there are variadic args before trying to access them?

The variadic argument facility does not *itself* provide a way to determine how many variadic arguments there are, or whether there are any at all.

> Or the only option for my use case is defining 2 different function, like so

A variadic function knows *from its non-variadic arguments* and from its general contract what variadic arguments to expect, and of what types.  `printf()` is the canonical example here: it knows from its format string what to expect of its variadic arguments.

If all the arguments to the current, non-variadic function have significance unsuited to be adapted to the purpose of informing about the presence of variasic arguments then you need at least a *different* function signature.  You don't necessarily need two functions, though.

If you do use two functions, however, then be aware that they will need different names.  C does not support function overloading.

If you want to preserve the current signature for existing callers, yet make the custom-format feature available to new ones, then one option would be to replace the current function with a macro that expands to a call to a replacement function with an augmented argument list.  Example:

```
void log_error_custom(char * file_name, int line_num, int err_code,
        const char * fmt, ...) {
    // ...
}

#define log_error(file, line, err) log_error_custom((file), (line), (err), "")
```